# How to expand URLs in C#?

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

If I have a URL like http://popurls.com/go/msn.com/l4eba1e6a0ffbd9fc915948434423a7d5, how do I expand it back to the original URL programmatically? Obviously I could use an API like [expandurl.com](http://expandurl.com/http://popurls.com/go/msn.com/l4eba1e6a0ffbd9fc915948434423a7d5) but that will limits me to 100 requests per hour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a request to the URL and check the status code returned. If `301` or `302`, look for a `Location` header, which will contain the "expanded URL":

```
string url = "http://popurls.com/go/msn.com/l4eba1e6a0ffbd9fc915948434423a7d5";

var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);            
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

var response = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();

if ((int) response.StatusCode == 301 || (int) response.StatusCode == 302)
{
    url = response.Headers["Location"];
}
```

Note: This solution presumes that only one redirect occurs. This may or may not be want you need. If you simply want to deobfuscate URLs from obfuscators (bit.ly et al) this solution should work well.

Comment: Although I've done this before, your solution presumes that there is no more than one redirect. Often a good enough solution, but I worked on one task where the final URI was actually important, in which case following the redirects was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find an answer.

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://popurls.com/go/msn.com/l4eba1e6a0ffbd9fc915948434423a7d5");
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    ServicePoint sp = req.ServicePoint;
    Console.WriteLine("End address is " + sp.Address.ToString());
```

Comment: This works, but it would be slightly more "expensive" than [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569851/how-to-expand-urls-in-c/2569869#2569869), which does only a single request ;)